# Terraform Validation Failing Over Correct Regex

Tags: terraform

Why cant terraform validate this regex with the example: testingname01? If I evaluate this expression here: https://regex101.com/r/ALETmb/1. It works and matches, but terraform validate returns me an │ Error: Invalid value for variable.

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name."
  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^(?!.*--)[a-zA-Z].{1,22}[a-z0-9A-Z]$", var.name))
    error_message = "Name must be between 3-24 alphanumeric characters, the name must begin with a letter, end with a letter or digit, and not contain consecutive hyphens."
  }
}
```

Comment: Of the regular expression "flavors" available in regex101, the closest to Terraform's regex language is "Golang", because Terraform is building on top of the Go regex implementation. If you select that flavor instead, you can see an error which might be a starting point for adapting this to something Terraform can accept.

Comment: For me, it highlights the first question mark as being invalid, which seems like a valid error message to me because `?` means "zero or one of the preceding pattern", but there is no preceding pattern. I assume in PCRE's language there's a special meaning to a `?` at the start of a parenthesis group, but the Go/Terraform regex language doesn't support that syntax. I don't know what that actually means in PCRE, but you'll need to find an alternative in [the `regex` function docs](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/regex).

Comment: Yeah, seems like Go's regex doesnt support negative lookahead...

Comment: One thing that makes debugging hard here is that in the context of `can` any failure (whether it be the regex not matching or the pattern not being valid) ends up being a validation error. To get better feedback I'd suggest running `terraform console` and trying `regex` calls from there, so that you can see the real errors that the `can` function is hiding.